# Filtrar valores de un campo a partir de una lista […] - Query Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, djangorestframework, django-admin

```
class Grupos(models.Model):
                grupo = models.CharField(max_length=300)
                familia =models.CharField(max_length=300)
                fg = models.CharField(max_length=300)
                status=models.IntegerField(default=1)
                f000=models.CharField(default=0,max_length=5)
                f001=models.CharField(default=0,max_length=5)
                f010=models.CharField(default=0,max_length=5)
                f011=models.CharField(default=0,max_length=5)
                f012=models.CharField(default=0,max_length=5)
                f015=models.CharField(default=0,max_length=5)
                f018=models.CharField(default=0,max_length=5)
                f020=models.CharField(default=0,max_length=5)
                f021=models.CharField(default=0,max_length=5)
                f022=models.CharField(default=0,max_length=5)


            fgod = form1.cleaned_data.get('fg')

            feature= Grupos.objects.filter(fg=fgod)

            listaFeatures=[]

            for item in feature:
                  listaFeatures.append(item.f000)
                  listaFeatures.append(item.f001)
                  listaFeatures.append(item.f010)
                  listaFeatures.append(item.f011)
                  listaFeatures.append(item.f012)
                  listaFeatures.append(item.f015)
                  listaFeatures.append(item.f018)
                  listaFeatures.append(item.f020)
                  listaFeatures.append(item.f021)
                  listaFeatures.append(item.f022)



            for item in listaFeatures:

                if (item!='0'):


                    listaItem =[]

                    listaItem.append(item)

                for i in listaItem:
                        query= Archivos.objects.filter(modelSerial=fgod, linea=station, status=1,feature=i)
```

fgod es obtenido de una lista desplegable

```
        fgod = form1.cleaned_data.get('fg')
```

Feature filtra sobre el campo fg en el modelo Grupos, donde el campo fg coincida con la variable fgod seleccionada en la lista desplegable

```
        feature= Grupos.objects.filter(fg=fgod)
```

Se crea una lista con nombre listaFeatures, en la cual se van a agregar los valores de lo siguiente campos los cuales estan el modelo Grupos  f000',    'f001', 'f010', 'f011', 'f012', 'f015', 'f018,  'f020,  'f021', 'f022'

```
        listaFeatures=[]

        for item in feature:
              listaFeatures.append(item.f000)
              listaFeatures.append(item.f001)
              listaFeatures.append(item.f010)
              listaFeatures.append(item.f011)
              listaFeatures.append(item.f012)
              listaFeatures.append(item.f015)
              listaFeatures.append(item.f018)
              listaFeatures.append(item.f020)
              listaFeatures.append(item.f021)
              listaFeatures.append(item.f022)
```

Se recorre las lista llamda listaFeatures

```
        for item in listaFeatures:
```

Si el item contiene un valor que es diferente de '0' el valor se añade a una nueva lista llamada listaItem

```
            if (item!='0'):


                listaItem =[]

                listaItem.append(item)
```

Ahora quiero filtrar el campo "feature" del modelo Archivos los valores que estan en la lista: listaItem;
sin embargo de la siguiente forma solo me muestra el ùltimo valor que trae la variable (i).

```
            for i in listaItem:
                    query= Archivos.objects.filter(modelSerial=fgod, linea=station, status=1,feature=i)
```

si por el contrario 
            pongo: feature=listaItem[i] en lugar de: feature=i

```
            for i in listaItem:
                    query= Archivos.objects.filter(modelSerial=fgod, linea=station, status=1,feature=listaItem[i])
```

me muestra el siguiente ERROR:"list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: Creo que debes agregar un poco más de información acerca de como construyes tus modelos, porque no me termino de enterar mucho que quieres hacer ni el tipo de los datos que se pueden usar

Comment: Información agregada